# Extending userdetails.User with custom user class and still generating table in MySql with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to extend org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User; so I can add a few custom properties of my own and still have everything work like normal.

A few questions...

I am using MySql so I need to make sure an ApplicationUser table is still created. So should I still tag the class with @Entity?

Should I still be adding a primary key such as private long id; to this class even though the User class it extends one already has private static final long serialVersionUID = 530L;?

I added my additional property, constructors that pass values using super, getters and setters for my additional properties.

I keep getting a message such as:
Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [username] on this ManagedType [com.xyz.myapi.model.ApplicationUser]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not have your persistence model extending `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User`

> I am using MySql so I need to make sure an ApplicationUser table is still created. So should I still tag the class with @Entity?

Yes, `@Entity` indicates its a JPA entity, or a representation of what your sql table maps to.

> Should I still be adding a primary key such as private long id; to this class even though the User class it extends one already has private static final long serialVersionUID = 530L?

Yes. Every `@Entity` class must have a primary key `@Id`, just like how you could have a AUTO_INCREMENT id column in MySql. This id could be generated in many different ways depending on the persistence provider (JPA implementation) or the underlying database. `serialVersionUID` has nothing to do with this.

> I keep getting a message such as: Unable to locate Attribute with the the given name [username] on this ManagedType [com.xyz.myapi.model.ApplicationUser]

I looked this up. It looks like you messed up the method for query derivation. Could be a spelling error or you have inheritance that isn't correct. But it's impossible to know without looking at the class.

A super simple example:

**ApplicationUser.class**:

```
@Entity
public class ApplicationUser {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, length = 32)
    @Size(max = 32)
    private String username;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;
    ...
}
```

**UserDetailsServiceImpl.class**

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    ApplicationUser user = userRepository.findByUsername(username).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException(username));
    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), getAuthorities());
}
```

Comment: I see you are adding String username and String password properties to ApplicationUser. Don't forget my ApplicationUser class extends: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User which already has those properties. I noticed when the MySql database tables are created it is not creating the fields from the org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User class (the username, password, and boolean check fields). Only my custom fields in ApplicationUser are being created. I see in your example you are not extending from org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User

Comment: After researching a bit further I realized that Hibernate will not create fields in the database for a superclass naturally. I started playing around with MappedSuperclass and Inherticance annotations and still no luck. This is why I am trying to figure out if it is a common thing to extend org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User. I can't find many example of other people doing it but the documentation says you can Subclass it.

Comment: You shouldn't. You are coupling your entity class with UserDetails from Spring Security. So any changes (Say change to field name) to `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` could break your entity model.

Comment: Cool I think I found exactly what I should be doing... instead of extending that User class I am now implementing UserDetails and creating my own implementation of it. Inside of the class I also have a List<ApplicationRole> and I made it so based on this list the getGrantedAuthorities method returns a list of SimpleGrantedAuthorities. Additionally, I created all of those boolean fields similar to how User had them and now they are all persisted in the DB. One small thing I had to do was make grantedAuthorities property Transient so JPA wouldn't try to add it to the DB structure.

Comment: Can you let me know if the above sounds like I am on the right track? This way in the loadUserByUsername method I can simply pull the user from the db, check for null, and return it. Rather than have to convert it to a class that implements UserDetails (in this case mine already does).

Comment: Almost. Again, you could have your own implementation of `UserDetails`, or subclass `userdetails.User`, however you like. But this implementation should be strictly separated from your persistence model, one perform auththentication/authorization and other stores data.  You should define your own user entity class and then query its relevant info to construct a `UserDetails` instance.

Comment: @ 夢のの夢 Ahhh I see so I should actually have two separate classes. One class for the persistence model and another that implements UserDetails. I would query into the persistence model class and then convert to UserDetails. If I really want to keep track of the boolean fields: accountNonExpired, accountNonLocked, credentialsNonExpired, and enabled... I could add them to my persistence model class and then map them to the UserDetails implemented class however necessary. Do a lot of people store these fields in their database or are they mostly determined based on other things?

Comment: They are really just "extras" and typically true by default, but it really depends on the use case of your business. So you could use table cols such as`createdOn`, `updatedOn`, `numberOfAttempts` to determine these boolean values. I personally never dealt with them since users for my database could never expire or log in as frequent as they like - probably bad security practices lol